# Remove NaN from Pandas Dataframe by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have **Dataframe** that have some **NaN** values in specfic columns (Dataframe looks like this,  By the way, the actual **Dataframe** is far larger than what I have shown bellow):

```
    source  battery   Temperature  time                      Distance
0   83512   98.0         NaN       2019-10-26T00:00:06.494Z   NaN
1   83512   NaN          23.0      2019-10-26T00:00:06.538Z   NaN
2   83512   NaN          NaN       2019-10-26T00:00:06.577Z   21.0
3   83512   98.0         NaN       2019-10-26T00:30:06.702Z   NaN
4   83512   NaN          23.0      2019-10-26T00:30:06.743Z   NaN
5   83512   NaN          NaN       2019-10-26T00:30:06.781Z   21.0
6   83512   98.0         NaN       2019-10-26T01:00:08.955Z   NaN
7   83512   NaN          23.0      2019-10-26T01:00:08.998Z   NaN
8   83512   NaN          NaN       2019-10-26T01:00:09.039Z   21.0
```

**I am trying to find a way to condense the frame so that it looks more like this:**

```
    source  battery   Temperature  time                      Distance
0   83512   98.0         23.0      2019-10-26T00:00:06.494Z  21.0     
1   83512   98.0         23.0      2019-10-26T00:30:06.702Z  21.0
2   83512   98.0         23.0      2019-10-26T01:00:08.955Z  21.0
```

In other words, I am trying to remove the NaN values from battery   Temperature, and Distance columns if time reading is nearly similar (for example, time= `2019-10-26T00:00:06.494Z, 2019-10-26T00:00:06.538Z, 2019-10-26T00:00:06.577Z`) get all the coresponding values for (source,battery, Temperature,time and Distance)

This is what I have so far.

```
enter code here
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests

URL = 'https://xxxxx.com'
req = requests.get(URL,auth=('xxx', 'xxx') )
text_data= req.text
json_dict= json.loads(text_data)
df= json_normalize(json_dict['measurements'])
df = df.rename(columns={'source.id': 'source', 'battery.percent.value': 'battery', 'c8y_TemperatureMeasurement.T.value': 'Temperature Or T','c8y_DistanceMeasurement.distance.value':'Distance'})
cols_to_keep =['source' ,'battery', 'Temperature Or T', 'time', 'Distance']
df_final = df[cols_to_keep] 
# this line doesnt give me the expected output 
df1 = df_final.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom grouper, checking the time difference in the `time` column, set a threshold (here `10 min` for instance) to determine the groups and use the result to keep the `firts` valid rows:

```
g = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).diff().gt(pd.Timedelta(10, 'min')).cumsum()
df.groupby(g).first()

      source  battery  Temperature                      time  Distance
time                                                                  
0      83512     98.0         23.0  2019-10-26T00:00:06.494Z      21.0
1      83512     98.0         23.0  2019-10-26T00:30:06.702Z      21.0
2      83512     98.0         23.0  2019-10-26T01:00:08.955Z      21.0
```